# cannot create navigation menu with HTML/CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I just completed basics in HTML/CSS, JavaScript, jQuery and php on codecademy. 
I am trying to make a website with html/css and jquery in codecademy codebits. Right now my navigation menus are acting weird. 
The main nav menus (primary) seem to be OK. But when hovering over one of the menus which has a sub menu, the primary menus go down along with the dropdown menus. 
I've been trying to solve it the whole day but to no avail :(
I've tried display: inline, display: inline-block, display: block but they don't help.
I've also tried setting position: to different settings but they don't help either. 
My html seems OK to me but maybe there are some errors. I doubt my css but after having tried for the whole day, I'm exhausted :(

**My html script:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>A first complete project</title>
<link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class = "header">  <!--Header Area -->
    <ul class = "mainMenu">  <!-- The main nav menu -->
        <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
        <li>About Us</li>
        <li>Contact Us</li>
        <li id = "services">Services 
        <!--Creating sub menu-->
            <ul class = "servicesSubMenu">
                <li>Basic Web Design</li>
                <li>Pro Web Design</li>
                <li>Advanced Web Design</li>
                <li id = "wordpressWebDesign">Wordpress Web 
                Design
                <!--Creating Sub-sub menu-->
                    <ul class = "wordpressSubMenu">
                        <li>Wordpress Installation</li>
                        <li>Wordpress customization</li>
                    </ul> 
                </li>     
            </ul>
        </li>    
    </ul>

</div>

<!--creating div class wrapper for sliderArea-->
<div class = "wrapper">
    <div class = "slideArea"> <!--Creating the slider-->

    </div>
</div>

<!--Creating the main footer-->
<div id = "mainFooter">
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2014 <a href = "https://www.hostbarrack.com">Hostbarrack</a></p>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**My css:**

```
/* ==== Settings for the main body
================================================= */
body {
    background-color: #454545;
}

/*======  Settings for the main nav menu
================================================== */
.mainMenu {
  border-radius: 10px; 
  background-color: #555555;
  font-family: seriff;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #389803;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.mainMenu li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.mainMenu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: #389803;
    height: 40px;
}

/* === Settings for the sub menu of the 'Services' Button
===================================================== */
.servicesSubMenu {
  font-family: seriff;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #389803;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.servicesSubmenu li {
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 8px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #454545;
    height: auto;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 1px;
    display: block;

}

/* === =Settings for the sub menu of 'Wordpress Web design' which is a sub menu of 'Services'
=========================================================*/
.wordpressSubMenu li {
    background-color: #606060;
}

/* ======== Settings for the slider area of home-page.
==================================================== */
.slideArea {
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #909090;
    height: 500px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 10px, 10px, 10px, 10px;
}

/* === Settings for the main footer area 
==================================================== */
#mainFooter {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#mainFooter a {
    color: #FEFE79;
/*does not work. check it again and remove this comment after finding the solution*/    
}
```

**My jQuery code:**

```
var main = function() {
    $(".servicesSubMenu").hide(); /* Hide sub menu when document
                                    loads */

    /* When hovering over 'Services' button in main nav menu */
    $("#services").hover(function() {
        $(".servicesSubMenu").slideToggle(80);
        $(".wordpressSubMenu").hide(); /* Hide sub-sub menu */
    });

    /* When hovering over sub-sub menu 'Wordpress Web Design'
      inside 'Services button. */
    $("#wordpressWebDesign").hover(function() {
      $(".wordpressSubMenu").slideToggle(80);
    });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

You can also see my codes and the test page at http://www.codecademy.com/sunoy14/codebits/r316c 
Please see the codebits in both full screen and the smaller screen. Shows different problematic layouts. 
I'd be really grateful for the help.

Thank you.

Comment: Please always add your code on this site, and also add here which error messages you are getting. Outside links to an example of your issue are welcome, but not reliable as they can become unavailable after time.

Comment: I have added the codes now. I was worried that the code would make my post too long and so I had not added it when posting the thread.

Comment: Hi. I just tried adding a code snippet after seeing Persijin's post. But I couldn't add it to my post. When I click insert to post, nothing happens. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at your code on the website.
You have not set the position value.
Position changes where it is going to display, and by default, it is set to relative. By changing it to absolute, the element does not get affected by the surrounding elements.

Try this code in the CSS file.

```
.servicesSubMenu {
  font-family: seriff;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #389803;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: That worked!! I had tried setting position to absolute in the .mainMenu, .mainMenu li and the .servicesMenu li. But I somehow never tried setting it  inside the .servicesMenu. I was thinking it had to be set in the sub menu div :D . Thanks a lot for saving me from the headache :)

Comment: There is another problem coming up :(    . When hovering over the services menu, the dropdown appears fine now. But it wavers or shivers for some time and is not stable. After a moment, it becomes stable. What could the problem be?  And is it possible for me to align the sub menu directly down below the services menu? The code provided by Persijin outputs submenus that are aligned directly below the parent menu. He uses only CSS though. I wonder the same could be applied to mine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code example of a navbar you are asking for.
I don't know if this is a way you want to do it since I don't use any Javascript.

```css
.navigation {
  background-color: gray;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 50px;
}
.menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.menu-item {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.menu-item:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
.menu-item .sub-item {
  display: none;
}
.menu-item:hover .sub-item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
}
.sub-item: hover {
  display: block;
}
.menu-item .sub-item a {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="navigation">
    <div class="menu-item">
      <div class="name">Home</div>
      <div class="sub-item">
        <a>link</a>
        <a>link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
      <div class="name">Contact</div>
      <div class="sub-item">
        <a>link</a>
        <a>link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was going to look for some css methods of doing it too. This is going to be useful.